# Having trouble understanding cross-validation results from scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python, scikit-learn

Actually, my question may just be about cross-validation in general. Here's what I'm doing: I'm trying to come up with a model using scikit-learn to learn on some data I've got. I've decided to use an SVM, using various kernels, to do the modelling. I've got about 50,000 data points from which to extract features. In an effort to make sure that my model is not over- or under-fitting, I've decided to run all of my models through cross-validation using scikit-learn's `cross_validation` functionality. I'm setting aside 40% of my training data for cross-validation, and so training on 60%.

I do this iteratively until I come up with a set of features and a model that gives me a cross-validation score of about 0.96. Great! Here's the problem - when I use this model to predict results for my test data, I only get a score of about 0.79! I don't understand that result. My question is, am I misunderstanding the cross validation score? Shouldn't I be able to expect similar results for my test data when using the model cross-validated to 0.96? I even used the GridSearchCV to come up with the best parameters to use for the SVM kernel. I also made sure to train on the full set of training data when training my model before running predict.

This is my first real attempt to use machine learning for a cool project, and I'm totally confused on my expectations.

Comment: to be clear: cross-validation uses 100% of the data. At each iteration, some p% of data is trained on, and (100-p)% is tested on, and the average score is returned. To say `I'm setting aside 40% of my training data for cross-validation, and so training on 60%.` sounds strange. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess I'm saying that p=0.6

Comment: Sp typically, p is something smaller, like .2 or .1, so that one would perform 5 or 10 iterations respectively. In sklearn's `cross_validation` function, are you inputing 60% of the data, or 100%? Another question: how many features do you have/extract, and at what stage do you extract features?

Comment: Interesting. You only train on 10% of the data and test on 90%, typically, in model selection?  My machine learning classes suggested 40% for testing was a good number. I'm inputting 100% of my training data to cross_validation, and setting the test_size parameter to 0.4.  I have about 200 features, which are extracted from my data right before training/cross-validation.

Comment: that test_size parameter is passed to train_test_split, which I use to partition the data.

Comment: sorry sorry, I mean p=90 or 80. I mixed the two up.

Comment: Ok, sounds like I may want to try partitioning my data a bit differently. I'll give that a try!

Comment: WAIT. You have commited overfitting, though it is very subtle. I'll write an answer explaining why.

Comment: Is there any signifcant difference in the the audio generation process between the training and validation set? For example, male sounds in training, female in validation. What kernel are you using?

Comment: I'm not aware of any difference in the audio generation process, but I feel fairly confident that there is no appreciable difference.  As for kernels, I've tried RBF, linear, and polynomial.  I used the GridSearchCV with various parameters to try to tune the various parameters to the different kernels; I used precision_score and recall_score as the guiding forces to do the tuning (basically, I just took the code from the scikit-learn page on grid search and modified it to run with my data!)

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: That's on another machine, but I can put some snippets up here when I get home.  Thanks, Cam!

Answer (score 3):

From section 7.10.2 of [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)(free online, and it's great):

Consider a classification problem with a large number of predictors, as may
arise, for example, in genomic or proteomic applications. A typical strategy
for analysis might be as follows:

1. Screen the predictors: find a subset of “good” predictors that show
   fairly strong (univariate) correlation with the class labels
2. Using just this subset of predictors, build a multivariate classifier.
3. Use cross-validation to estimate the unknown tuning parameters and
   to estimate the prediction error of the final model.

Is this a correct application of cross-validation? Consider a scenario with
N = 50 samples in two equal-sized classes, and p = 5000 quantitative
predictors (standard Gaussian) that are independent of the class labels.
The true (test) error rate of any classifier is 50%. We carried out the above
recipe, choosing in step (1) the 100 predictors having highest correlation
with the class labels, and then using a 1-nearest neighbor classifier, based
on just these 100 predictors, in step (2). Over 50 simulations from this
setting, the average CV error rate was 3%. This is far lower than the true
error rate of 50%.

What has happened? The problem is that the predictors have an unfair
advantage, as they were chosen in step (1) on the basis of all of the samples.
Leaving samples out after the variables have been selected does not cor-rectly mimic the application of the classifier to a completely independent
test set, since these predictors “have already seen” the left out samples.

We selected the 100 predictors having largest correlation with the class labels over all 50 samples. Then we chose a random set of 10 samples, as we would do in five-fold cross-validation, and computed the correlations of the pre-selected 100 predictors
with the class labels over just these 10 samples (top panel). We see that
the correlations average about 0.28, rather than 0, as one might expect

Comment: I think I partially understand, but I'm not sure how to remedy my situation.  I'm starting with a large number of AIFF files, and I need to get the data from these files into a form that can be submitted to the learning algorithm.  I'm using scikit-audiolab to extract the features directly from the AIFF files, and these are what I'm passing to the cross-validation code.  It sounds to me like you are saying that this is invalid.  (By the way, thanks for the text reference - I'll definitely check it out!)  How do I get data to the cross-validation without pre-selecting the features?

Comment: By the way, thanks a million for the responses, Cam - I really do appreciate the guidance.  I'm very new to this stuff, but it has definitely piqued my interest in a big way!

Comment: So the answer I proposed was if you were actively selecting features, but it sounds like you are not doing this. The test data that you get .79 on: is this not involved at all in the training/cross validation part?

Comment: Nope, that data is totally set aside.  Once I have selected my model using *only* the training data, I then run the model to predict the results on the test data.  The test data - the one where I get the score of 0.79 - is definitely in *no* way used to select the model and is thus not involved in the 0.96 CV score I get.

Comment: The test data is also not used for training.

Comment: ok I understand. That is good practice btw. A dataset used in that is called a *validation set*. I have a few more questions, but this answer is now irrelvant so I'll move back up to comments.

Answer (score 1):

What is the average value and standard deviation of the resulting recognition rates? If you have a high deviation, that would point out that your classifier is sensible to training data, i.e. you might be overfitting.

If the deviation is high, what if you use 70-30% or 80-20%. Do you still have the same problem?. Do you shuffle the samples before splitting them into groups?

Since you are using SVM, another possibility could be that if the distribution of samples is skewed across classes (you get by change a lot of samples from one class and very few from another) that you run into this problem too. A possible solution would be to try stratified cross validation in scikit-learn. The point is to ensure same number of samples per class.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your validation set is left completely untouched during `GridSearchCV`. If so, it would help if you described your design matrix.

Nonetheless, I personally find `GridSearchCV` functions tend to overfit. Therefore, I suggest you try either a Lasso linear model (and thus use `LassoCV`) or a [ElasticNet](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20%282005%29%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf) model (and thus use `ElasticNetCV`).